# I AM CREATING CONSTRAINTS IN A TABLE

Tags: oracle-apex

```
CREATE TABLE ACTORS
(
    ACTOR_ID NUMBER(10),
    STAGE_NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    BIRTH_DATE DATE
);

ALTER TABLE ACTORS 
    ADD CONSTRAINTS PK_ACTOR_ID PRIMARY KEY(ACTOR_ID);

ALTER TABLE ACTORS 
    ADD CONSTRAINTS FK_ 
        FOREIGN KEY(STAR_BILLING_ID) REFERENCES STAR_BILLINGS(STAR_BILLING_ID);

CREATE TABLE STAR_BILLINGS
(
    ACTOR_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    TITLE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    STAR_BILLING_ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    COMMENTS VARCHAR2(40)
);
```

Error:

> ORA-00904: "STAR_BILLING_ID": invalid identifier ORA-06512

Comment: You **cannot** create a foreign key to a table that doesn't exist yet...... **first** create your two tables - **THEN** add the foreign key - so that the table you reference does exist at the time the FK constraint is established. Also, I believe it should be `ADD CONSTRAINT` (singular) - not `ADD CONSTRAINTS` ......

Comment: That also looks like you're going the wrong way; as `actors` doesn't have a `star_billing_id` column and it wouldn't make much sense anyway (an actor can't have star billing in more than one play/film?), do you perhaps want the `star_billings.actor_id` to a FK pointing to `actors.actor_id`?